# Return a flux object when takeUntil condition is met

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I receive a stream of dictionary. The keys in the dictionary are `token`,`isAnswer`,`isSources`. Now, the moment i receive `isAnswer` as false, i wanted to stop the stream and return a flux with a different message. But i couldn't achieve this logic. Below is the code written. If you know how to achieve, can you please help me.Thank you

```
 public Flux<StreamData> streamChatbotResponse(String query, Long communityId, String widgetUserId, ChatBotBotType botType) {
 

        return Flux.create(sink -> {
                            dataStream.takeUntil(data -> !Boolean.parseBoolean(data.getIsAnswer()))
                            .subscribe(data -> { // start of data stream
                                if (!data.getToken().isEmpty()) {
                             
    
               if (!data.getToken().equals("Done")) {
    
                                        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(data.getIsSources())) {
                                            var parsedData = parseUrlString(data.getToken());
                                            var sources = parseSourcesInStreaming(parsedData);
                                            // For the last token send True else send False.
    //
                                            for (var url : sources) {
                                                var streamData = new StreamData().setToken(url).setIsSources("True")
                                                        .setIsFinish("False").setIsAnswer("True").setExternalId(ts);
                                                response.append(url);
                                                sink.next(streamData);
                                            }
                                            // I need to know what is the status of the conversation.Is it answered or not.
                                            chatBotConversationService.saveWebBotConversation(
                                                    chatBotConversation.getQuery(), response.toString(), "", ts, communityId, chatBot,
                                                    ChatBotConversationStatus.ANSWERED, widgetUserId, botType);
    
                                        } else {
                                            var streamData = new StreamData().setToken(data.getToken()).setIsSources("False").setIsFinish("False").setIsAnswer("True").setExternalId(ts);
                                            response.append(data.getToken());
                                            sink.next(streamData);
                                        }
    
                                    } else {
                                        // Stream reaches done status. End of the answer
                                        var streamData = new StreamData().setToken("").setIsSources("False").setIsFinish("True").setExternalId(ts).setIsAnswer("False");
                                        response.append(data.getToken());
                                        sink.next(streamData);
    
                                    }
                                }
    
                            if(!Boolean.parseBoolean(data.getIsAnswer())) {
                                chatBotConversationService.saveWebBotConversation(
                                        chatBotConversation.getQuery(), chatBot.getNoAnswer(), "", ts, communityId, chatBot,
                                        ChatBotConversationStatus.NO_ANSWER, widgetUserId, botType);
                                sayDefaultAnswer(chatBot.getNoAnswer());
    
                            }
    
                        },sink::error, sink::complete); // end of data stream
                    });
}
```

Below is the sayDefaultAnswer

```
private static Flux<StreamData> sayDefaultAnswer(String message) {
        var ts = String.valueOf(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
        var streamData = new StreamData().setToken(message)
                .setIsSources("False").setIsFinish("True").setIsAnswer("False").setExternalId(ts);
        return Flux.create(sink -> {
            sink.next(streamData);
        });
    }
```

And the definition of StreamData is

```
public class StreamData {

    private String token;

    private String isFinish;

    private String isSources;

    private String isAnswer;

    private String externalId;
}
```

Atleast any hints would be helpful.